# How to store each value into one array?

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have problem to make some id into one array
Maybe you can help me...This image is the result 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Jy9.png)

and this is my code

```
 $.each(data.rows, function (i, ele) {
    var tes = ele.ID;                
   console.log('ItemID', tes);

}
```

The Result that i want expect is each item in the one array like this 'ItemID = [22,2,43,2]'

Comment: can you show some code which you've tried?

Comment: Could you post your origin input data?

Comment: please be more precise, show us what you tried and also what you'd expect to have as a result.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @Kunal Dholiya I have tried code like in my question and the result there are in the image

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih Could you explain clearly?

Comment: @Salketer the result that i expected is like this 'ItemID [3,2,1,2]' i have tries the code above and the result like in the image

Comment: @DominicAmalJoeF i have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const idArray = data.rows.map((r)=>r.ID)

//More verbose
const idArray = data.rows.map(function (ele){
    return r.ID;
});
```

Map creates a loop through all the values in the array and uses the return of the function passed to create a new array.

EDIT:
I'm not sure I understand, you'd want an array of array?

```
const idArray = data.rows.map(function (ele){
    return [r.ID];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... each id now there are in one array...but the array loop through all the values... the result is like this ItemID [21,3,4] ,ItemID [21,3,4]

Comment: Not sure I understand... maybe this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var tempArray = []     
 $.each(data.rows, function (i, ele) {
    tempArray.push(ele.ID);                
 }
 // tempArray will be the solution
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to each ID into one array  so the result is like this ItemID = [1,2,4] not like this ItemID = [1], ItemID = [2]

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [1,2,3,4]; // Assuming this array contains rows data
var resultArray = [];  // Result array

var ids = data.map(function (ele){
  return ele;
});

resultArray.push(ids.join(',')); // Join ids using "," separator 

console.log(resultArray); // ["1,2,3,4"]
```